# How to Laravel mobile app api for facebook login

Tags: facebook, api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Hi i'm working on a web with Laravel. On the web, I use socialite to login with Facebook, but I don't know how to do that with api for mobile to connect.
On the web, the flow is the user request to the website, socialite will redirect to facebook to obtain data and redirect back to the  redirect url that we register to do authentication.

I don't know if with mobile app is the same? 
How can I do it since there is only 1 redirect url and how to detect if the request is from website or from mobile app. Because request from website, ultimately is return view and request from mobilr is return json, right?

Or the mobile side, mobilr developer  will do the obtaining data then send it to the website through api to authenticate?

Please help me on this. Thank u. Sorry for my bad English. If anyone does not understand my situation please ask me again.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a mobile app, you should use the Facebook Mobile SDK to preform Facebook login instead of doing it the website way. On Facebook, you can have different settings for iOS and Android (and other platforms), so you won't need to worry about knowing which platform the user is using.

When the user authenticates using the mobile app, you can pass the Facebook `access_token` back to your database via an API.